# Counting numbers after decimal point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in JavaScript. Is it possible to check how many numbers are after the decimal point? I tried to do it using `a.toString().split(".")[1]`), but if there is no decimal point in the number, there is an error. What should I do if I want the system to do nothing if there is no decimal point?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. You can also `.includes('.')` to test if it contains a decimal along with `.length` to return the length of the decimal portion.

```js
function decimalCount (number) {
  // Convert to String
  const numberAsString = number.toString();
  // String Contains Decimal
  if (numberAsString.includes('.')) {
    return numberAsString.split('.')[1].length;
  }
  // String Does Not Contain Decimal
  return 0;
}

console.log(decimalCount(1.123456789)) // 9
console.log(decimalCount(123456789))   // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a string, split on “.”, then when there is no “.” to split on, assume it’s empty string `''` (the part you’re missing), then get said string’s length:

```js
function numDigitsAfterDecimal(x) {
  var afterDecimalStr = x.toString().split('.')[1] || ''
  return afterDecimalStr.length
}

console.log(numDigitsAfterDecimal(1.23456))
console.log(numDigitsAfterDecimal(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if no dot is available, then return zero, otherwise return the delta of the lenght and index with an adjustment.

```js
function getDigits(v) {
    var s = v.toString(),
        i = s.indexOf('.') + 1;
    return i && s.length - i;
}

console.log(getDigits(0));
console.log(getDigits(0.002));
console.log(getDigits(7.654321));
console.log(getDigits(1234567890.654321));
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you need is:

```
number.split('.')[1].length
```

It checks if there are any numbers after the dot which separates the number from its decimal part.

I'm not sure if you are able to use `split` on numbers though. If not, parse it to a string.

Comment: Also add && number.includes('.') to condition if you want to be sure this  number contains decimal part.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to convert the decimal number to string and then get the count of character after decimal point,

```
var a = 10.4578;
var str = a.toString();
if(str){
   var val = str.split('.');
   if(val && val.length == 2){
     alert('Length of number after decimal point is ', val[1].length);
   } else {
    alert('Not a decimal number');
   }
}
```

The output is `4`

Comment: My problem is, when there's no decimal point in a number, script crushes

Comment: I've made a change